# Detect notification and its info when app is launched directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using the pushPlugin to manage notifications in the app.

When a user clicks a notification, the app launches and the onNotificationAPN() function fires as expected.

Is there a way to detect if the user launches the app directly (by clicking the app icon), while a notification is present? Currently the onNotificationAPN() doesn't fire in this scenario, even though the app's icon has the little red number to show it has a notification.